# How to use a samba login to mount a luks container?

Tags: samba, luks

Our server has an (dm-crypt/LUKS) encrypted project directory which is currently mounted via SSH before its samba share can be accessed - and obviously no one remembers to unmount it afterwards.

(How) can samba be configured such that it mounts the container via the windows credentials transmitted either way and such that ideally it unmounts the container after either all users disconnected or after a given timeout?